# C# and C++ code in same .NET application?

Tags: c#, c++, .net

I'm supposed to work with Open CV, which can be programmed in C++ and deploy it in a .NET graphic interface application. I'd really like to work with C # for the interface traits.

What's the best approach for this?

Comment: First result from google for "Open CV C#": http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page Does that help?

Comment: Also, you might want to study [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI) a managed version of C++, which can be quite useful for creating interop code between native C++ and C#.

Comment: Aha, I know about egmu CV, but I don't really want to use a wrapper though. Can you explain a bit more or maybe answer about any simple C++/CLI app, @ChrisO

Comment: I'd still recommend EmguCV, otherwise you'll have to do all that work yourself to write the wrappers/interop.

Answer (score 3):

I know of two ways that C# and C++ can be used in the same application.

The simplest way works where the components to be written in C++ and C# can be separated such that one component relies on the other, but they are not mutually dependent. In this case just create two assemblies, one in C# and one in VC++, and reference one from the other. This is the simplest way to do it, not least because it is supported in the UI of Visual Studio.

However, that approach will not work if there is a mutual dependency, ie, class A needs to know about class B and class B needs to know about class A, where class A is to be written in C++ and class B is to be written in C#. It is still possible to write the classes in different languages like that, using a lesser known feature of .NET called multi-file assemblies, or netmodules.

See [How to: Build a Multifile Assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/226t7yxe.aspx) and [Multifile Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/168k2ah5.aspx) for instructions. It is useful to remember that the C++ compiler is generally more clever than the others. I seem to remember the procedure was to get C# to compile its half to a NetModule, then pass that to the C++ compiler and linker which was capable of linking it to the C++ parts and creating the final assembly.

An alternative approach, if you only intend to write a small amount of C# code, would be to learn the VC++ syntax for the .NET features you want to use and avoid C# altogether. VC++ can declare managed interfaces and types just like C# can, and if you will not be writing much actual code in C# then this might be easier.